# Why alert show before html element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple html code below. The alert dialog is shown before the html and the innerHTML only shown after click OK on dialog.

Question is how to show the html element "sort_arr" before alert dialog

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Sort</h2>

<p id="orig_arr"></p>
<p id="sort_arr"></p>
<button onClick="abcSort()"/>Sort Alphabet</button>
<button onClick="numSort()"/>Sort Numeric</button>

    <script>
        var arr = [1, 3, 11, 200, 8, 201, 1000, 50000];
        var new_arr = [2,1,1,5,7,100,3,2];
        document.getElementById("orig_arr").innerHTML = "Original array " + arr;
        
        function abcSort() {
            document.getElementById("sort_arr").innerHTML = "Abc sort : " + arr.sort();
        }
        
        function numSort() {    
            document.getElementById("sort_arr").innerHTML = "Abc sort : " + arr.sort(function(a,b) {return a-b});       
            alert(new_arr.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b} ));            
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here is answer => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082452/javascript-alert-box-shows-up-before-executing-previous-statement

Comment: Add some delay so DOM will get updated.

Comment: @SantoshShinde So Changes in the browser doesn't show up as long as your Javascript code is running. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that, you need to run the alert message on the next event cycle. You could do that with `setTimeout()` with an empty delay. Like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Sort</h2>

<p id="orig_arr"></p>
<p id="sort_arr"></p>
<button onClick="abcSort()"/>Sort Alphabet</button>
<button onClick="numSort()"/>Sort Numeric</button>

    <script>
        var arr = [1, 3, 11, 200, 8, 201, 1000, 50000];
        var new_arr = [2,1,1,5,7,100,3,2];
        document.getElementById("orig_arr").innerHTML = "Original array " + arr;
        
        function abcSort() {
            document.getElementById("sort_arr").innerHTML = "Abc sort : " + arr.sort();
        }
        
        function numSort() {    
            document.getElementById("sort_arr").innerHTML = "Abc sort : " + arr.sort(function(a,b) {return a-b});       
            setTimeout(() => alert(new_arr.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b} )));            
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaination. And solution worked for me :)