# File deleted before downloaded in Ajax call in Asp.net MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am generating a excel file by using the Ajax call to my Action in my controller class in my ASP.net MVC application.Its working fine but the problem occures some time when my file is in downloading stage and the ajax call delete it.If there is any way without SetTimeout then please tell me.

**Generate Excel File**

```
$.ajax({
url: "@Url.Action("GenerateReport", "ClientAdmin")",
type: "POST",
data: { reportStart: reportStart, reportEnd: reportEnd},
dataType: "json",
traditional: true,
success: function (downloadUrl) {
    //Download excel file
    window.location = "/ClientAdmin/Download?file=" + downloadUrl;
    //Delete excel file
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("DeleteReportFile", "ClientAdmin")",
        type: "POST",
        data: { file: downloadUrl },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (downloadUrl) {
        },
        error: function () {
            AlertShow("Error!", "Oops! An error occured");
        }
    })
},
error: function () {
    AlertShow("Error!", "Oops! An error occured");
    }
})
```

Comment: keep the ajax call 2 inside ajax call 1 complete function . cheers

Comment: sorry @super cool the ajax call 2 is already inside 1st ajax call success..and the problem is with following line because it download the excel file and before its completion the 2nd ajax call fires                                                     //Download excel file
window.location = "/ClientAdmin/Download?file=" + downloadUrl;

Comment: yes i just noticed it . err ! sorry . have you tried keeping in complete ? let us know

Comment: nopes same results with complete...... :(    @super cool

Comment: I think you question can be simplified by asking: "Event when browser receives file download"

Attempts are made to answer that question in this SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4168965/1099945

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need jQuery "when".

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

```
$.when( $.ajax( "test.aspx" ) ).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
  alert( jqXHR.status ); // Alerts 200
});
```

this is to force something to be synchronous. 
(One can find the credited answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338484/jquery-trigger-custom-event-synchronously))

**EDIT**

as I am not sure how to test your case I might suggest another solution.
Try handling "file downloaded" event somehow and then trigger the delete function. 
Here is a possible useful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download) and [blog](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2533-tracking-file-download-events-using-javascript-and-coldfusion.htm).