# Showing incorrect display

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to return the display value after a button is clicked, but it doesn't return the correct value.

My element: `<div id="my_div" style="display: none;"></div>`

After button click: `<div id="my_div" style="display: block;"></div>`

Javascript:

```
(function () {
  $('#button').trigger('click');

  return document.getElementById('my_div').style.display;
})();
```

Returns:

> "none"

Without clicking the button (just executing `document.getElementById('my_div').style.display`) I get the correct output:

Executing in console:

```
(function () {
  return document.getElementById('my_div').style.display;
})();
```

Returns:

> "block"

Comment: Do you have a button that display that div on the click event?

Comment: Yes = After click button: <div id="my_div" style="display: block;"></div>

Comment: Show your click handler.

Comment: jQuery’s `.trigger()` is *asynchronous* - it doesn’t wait for the event handlers to execute before returning. This means the next line of code *may* (and in your case does) execute before the event handlers do. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13338585/1813169) for a workaround

Comment: I do not have click hander it because I'm running on a site that is not mine, but I'm sure that when you click the button the display of none goes to block

Comment: Any solution for this? MTCoster

Comment: Can you past the site URL here?

Comment: The site contains register, login etc.. I think the problem is being what MTCoster said

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("#my_div).css('display')` to return display value.

```js
(function () {
  // On click
  $('#my_div').on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).css('display'));
  });
})();
```

```css
/* For testing purpose */
#my_div {
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_div" style="display:block"></div>
```

Comment: Return: undefined

Comment: @Slinidy test Snippet above does return `block` as result. Try running snippet and clicking on gray block. For testing purpose I used `console.log` to catch the value - you can change it to `return` if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

HTML:

```
<div id="my_div" style="display: none;">
</div>

<button id="button"> Click </button>
```

JS:

```
const myDiv = document.getElementById("my_div");

$("button").click(function() {
 console.log(myDiv.style.display);
 return myDiv.style.display;
});
```

Working pen [Link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/omagLe)

Comment: You can check the result on your browser's console.

Comment: Return: undefined

Comment: Can you post your whole code? Maybe your object name is not "myDiv".

Answer (score 0):

That's how it worked

```
$("#my_button").trigger('click');
setTimeout(test, 1000);
function test() { if (document.getElementById('my_div').style.display === 'block')
    alert('test');
}
```

But I do not know if this is the best option