# How to await ALL of the Listeners execution for Custom jQuery Event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, async-await, listener

```
$(document).on('custom-event', listener1 );
$(document).on('custom-event', listener2 );

function listener1() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
    })
}

function listener2() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 10000);
    })
}


$(document).trigger('custom-event');
const afterAwaiting = true; // Need to await 10 seconds after previous line of code to execute this statement
```

I've triggered custom **Event** - `custom-event`.

Need to await All of the Listeners execute its code,

then continue to execute next statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution by using `when`.

```
await $.when( $(document).trigger('custom-event') )

const afterAwaiting = true;
```

**jQuery** runs Custom Events **Synchronously** according to 
the question

[jQuery trigger custom event synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338484/jquery-trigger-custom-event-synchronously)

Or it works even without `await`

```
$(document).trigger('custom-event')
```